# get element id that is generated using for loop and reload that div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

hello i have a html page that generates the div ids using a for loop how ever i want to reload a specific div using its id that is generated by the loop, here is my html code

```
    {% for list in metrics_stats['metrics_list'] %}
            <div class="chart-row row" id="{{list[0]}}_parent metrics">

                <div class="chart-user col-sm-3" id="{{list[0]}}_user">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h4 class="chart-title " id="{{list[8]}}_title">
                             <form>Per User: &nbsp; 
                                <select class = "action-btn " id="inputDays">
                                    <option value="{{list[8]}}">120 days</option>
                                    <option value="{{list[7]}}">60 days</option>
                                </select>
                                <br><br>
                                <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
                            </form>
                            <p id="daysInputForm"></p>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="chart chart-pie" id="{{list[8]}}"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

So, every time the user chooses an option with value 60 the div below it with id="{{list[8]}}" should reload how can i achieve this without having to reload the entire page
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

my design pattern is to use classes to tag the function of the element.  in your case, instead of using id={{list[8]}}, i'd identify the chart with class="chart chart-pie js-chart".  then i'd use relative dom relationships to find this class when the select option changes.  my naming convention is to start jquery dom elements with a $prefix so i know that i don't also need to wrap them in $(var).

so my jquery would look something like:

```
$('.action-btn').change(function(e) {
  var $pdiv = $(this).parents('.chart-user');
  var $chart = $pdiv.find('.js-chart');
  .. use chart now to do your reload behavior here
});
```

as i'm not quite sure what it would take to reload your chart div, i'd be glad to edit this as you provide more info.